# find positive prime number

Tags: prime-numbers

Can anyone help on this?

> What is the positive integer such that the sum of the positive integer and 100 is a square number, and the sum of the positive integer and 168 is also a square number?

Here is what I did: assume the positive integer being $x$, then 
$$ x+100=y^2$$
$$x+168=z^2$$
This gives $(z-y)(z+y)=68=17*2^2$. There are many possibilities. Is there an simple way to find the answer from here?

Comment: Not that many possibilities: $68$ has $6$ divisors only, so only $3$ pairs to consider.

Comment: Hint: $z \pm y$ have the same parity.

Comment: What does this have to do with prime numbers?

Comment: Your title says *positive prime number*. If you can, please change your title to describe the actual question you have. Or, if you are really asking for a prime integer, add that to the body of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Not that many possibilities: $68$ has $6$ divisors only, so only $3$ pairs to consider:

$z-y=1, z+y=68$

$z-y=2, z+y=34$

$z-y=4, z+y=17$

Add @dxiv's remark and only one pair is left.